# How do I handle validation errors in ruby on rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, error-handling

I am new to ruby and I am working on an error structure to be sent as response to my api. Currently, validation errors are returned like:

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Profile update was unsuccessfull",
"errors": {
    "first_name": [
        "is too short (minimum is 3 characters)"
    ],
    "phone_number": [
        "Enter a valid us phone number"
    ]
}
```

}

but I want something like:

```
{
"status": 400,
"message": "Profile update was unsuccessfull",
"errors": {
    "first_name": "firstname "is too short (minimum is 3 characters)",
    "phone_number": "Enter a valid us phone number"
}
```

}

My model:

```
validates :first_name, :last_name, :state, :referral_method, presence: true, length: { minimum: 3, maximum: 25 }
validates :phone_number, format: { with: VALID_PHONE_REGEX, message: "Enter a valid us phone number" }, if: :phone_number_changed?
```

Controller:

```
# Handle validation errors
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid do |exception|
 messages = exception.record.errors.messages
 messages.map {|k,v| messages[k]=v[0] }
 @response = { status: Status.bad_request, message: Message.profile_not_updated, 
 errors:messages}
 json_response(@response, :bad_request)
end
```

Comment: Try `messages  = exception.record.errors.full_messages`

Comment: `{
    "status": 400,
    "message": "Profile update was unsuccessfull",
    "errors": [
        "First name is too short (minimum is 3 characters)",
        "Phone number Enter a valid us phone number"
    ]
}`. That what I get @Emu

Comment: What would you do if there were multiple errors on one field (e.g. `first_name` is too short and contains an illegal character, say)? That's probably the reason it's using an array here, so there can be multiple messages. Generally, with Rails, it's best to go with what Rails wants unless you've got a good reason not to (and personal taste isn't a good enough reason, unfortunately). If you mess with Rails conventions, the whole thing can start to unravel one piece at a time!

Comment: Yes. I have come to see that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could overwrite default active record translations:

```yaml
---
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            first_name:
              too_short: First name is too short (minimum is 3 characters)
            phone_number:
              too_short: Enter a valid us phone number
```

You can have a deeper in the documentation here: 
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#error-message-scopes